# What does "complete" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> This offer only applies to the members who make hotel bookings through our travel page
>   and complete their travel.

Does "complete" mean finish? Does it mean "this offer only applies to the member who book (...) and finish traveling"?

I read it from a T&C article. I can't find the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means to finish their travel, or, with other words,  make the travel from start to finish, not only some parts of the travel.